# Keras NASNet training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I intend to:

1. Train NASNet from scratch on a dataset
2. Re-train only the last layer of NASNet (transfer learning)

and compare their relative performance. From the documentation i see:

`keras.applications.nasnet.NASNetLarge(input_shape=None, include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)`

However the documentation is confusing be a bit.

Questions:

1. For transfer learning, do I set `include_top = True` and `classes = (num_classes)`, freeze all the layers except the last one, then train that?
2. Is it a requirement to have input images in the same shape as specified? NASNet requires (331,331,3) but that is quite large and i see imagenet being trained with diff sizes. Can I use smaller images such as (120,120,3) and replace the top layer? This would still be considered transfer learning right? However, the NASNet last layer seems to be a special type of cell, how would I implement that?
3. If I want to train from scratch, can I confirm that i set `include_top = False`, and add fully connected layers to the end?

Ideally if there's a tutorial that shows how to train NASNet from scratch as well as via transfer learning on a new dataset that'd be great. I found one for imagenet, but he built the model layers himself instead of using `keras.applications`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers for your questions:

```
For transfer learning, do I set include_top = True and classes = 
(num_classes), freeze all the layers except the last one, then train 
that?
```

When loading any model that you want to use for transfer learning, if you set the “include_top” argument to False, the fully-connected output layers of the model used to make predictions is not loaded, allowing you to add a  new output layer to be added and trained.

```
Is it a requirement to have input images in the same shape as 
specified? NASNet requires (331,331,3) but that is quite large and i 
see imagenet being trained with diff sizes. Can I use smaller images 
such as (120,120,3) and replace the top layer? This would still be 
considered transfer learning right? However, the NASNet last layer 
seems to be a special type of cell, how would I implement that?
```

It is very important for you to reshape the images, so that they are of the same size of the images of the pretrained model(Ex. NasNet) or else it will lead to bias.

```
If I want to train from scratch, can I confirm that i set include_top = 
False, and add fully connected layers to the end?
```

'include_top' argument is not related to whether you have to train entire model or freeze the model. Below is the example on how to train the entire model and also a part of the model:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
# or if we want to set the first 20 layers of the network to be non- 
trainable
for layer in model.layers[:20]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[20:]:
    layer.trainable=True
```